# Append Data to Byte Array

Tags: c#, string, arrays

Currently, I am reading data from a binary file (File.ReadAllBytes), converting this byte array into a string and appending data onto this string. Lastly, I am converting the string back into a byte array and writing the data back into a new file.

Yeah - this method is fairly idiotic, and I've been curious as to whether or not there is some way to append this *new* data onto the end of the byte array (in the form of a byte).

```
String s = @"C:\File.exe";
Byte b[] = File.ReadAllBytes(s);

String NewString = ConvertToString(b[]);

NewString = NewString + "Some Data";

b[] = ConvertToByteArray(NewString);
File.WriteAllBytes(b[]);
```

// ConvertToByteArray and ConvertToString represent functions that converts string > Byte > string.

What I would like to do:

```
b[] = file.readallbytes(s)
b = b + "new Data"
file.writeallbytes(b[])
```

Thank you very much for any insight on the matter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should get used to working with Streams - in this case you could use a `MemoryStream` to achieve the exact same thing without all those nasty arrays.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inFilePath);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // You could also just use StreamWriter to do "writer.Write(bytes)"
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        writer.Write("Some Data");
    }

    File.WriteAllBytes(outFilePath, ms.ToArray());
}
```

Admitedly this looks a whole load more complicated than your code, but under the covers what it's doing is more efficient.

Of course if you are just writing to another file (or even the same file) you can simply write directly to the file and skip the need for a `byte` array or `MemoryStream` entirely - this is the beauty of streams.

Comment: This worked exactly as I had envisioned. Thank you very much for your time. (All of you).

Answer (score 5):

Use `FileStream`, seek to the end of the file, then write what you need:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(s, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    fs.Seek(SeekOrigin.End);
    fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

If you really need to read the whole file, then just use `Array.Resize` to make your buffer bigger, and copy over the part you want to append.

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
Array.Resize(ref data, data.Length + toAppend.Length);
Array.Copy(toAppend, 0, data, data.Length - toAppend.Length, toAppend.Length);
File.WriteAllBytes(s, data);
```

There's no "shorthand" for this, sorry. :\

---

If the entire point of this is to append a *string*, just use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx)!

Comment: are you suggesting that I use filestream to read the binary file as well?

Comment: @Evan: No, sorry, see my edit. That was assuming you didn't actually need to read the entire file; if you do, use `Array.Resize`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`List<Byte>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), add every byte from the initial `ReadAllBytes` using `AddRange`, and then add the next set of bytes. Finally, use `CopyTo` to copy all bytes to an array (of size `List.Length`).

Comment: I was just curious, do you think you could give me a quick example of how to join the following?

byte[] bData;
string sData = "test data";
 bData = bData + Convert.ToByte(sData);

I did some reading on list<byte> but I'm still somewhat confused.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to append something to the file, then you should be using a FileStream and a StreamWriter:

```
        using (var f = File.Open(@"C:\File.exe", FileMode.Append))
        using (var w = new StreamWriter(f))
            w.Write("new Data");
```

or something similar to this.

If you just want to append some bytes:

```
        using (var f = File.Open(@"C:\File.exe", FileMode.Append))
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[] { 69, 65, 66, 67 };
            f.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array with size of the sum of two separate arrays, then copy your arrays to it.

Comment: I think by "sum" you mean "concatenation" or something, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad a1.Lenght + a2.Lenght that is. My English is not good, sad, but true :)